# Unknowingly Did Full Pradakshina in Vetakkorumakan Temple

Tags: temple

I'm wearing mala and in 41 day vratha to go to shabarimala.I visited a Shiva temple where the deity is in Kirathamoorthy form/Vetakkorumakan.

There was no rope/block to prevent full Pradakshina.So unknowingly Did Full pradaskshina.

After doing so when I asked about pradaskshina ..It was said that only half should be done like in normal shiva Temple.But in our Vetakkorumakan temple we do full pradaskshina.... I was wondering if I did something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more regional practice.

In Kerala the parikrama way is different. In TN usually not very strict way is followed.

Further as per the tradition if a shiva linga is covered with a roof then you can do its full parikramA.

In most north indian temples also they do full parikrama.

So.i dont think you have done anything bad.

Ultimately only devotion matters.

Comment: Thanks .... Did you mean this " you have done anything good"... Did you mean 'Bad'

Comment: @techno sorry it was a.typo. welcome to the forum and wish you luck in your spiritual journey.